# Python -for loop to select each files in directory

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a simple query in python 3. I have a path as var where I am passing the file path from the directory. File out.txt contains a list of many files path

Example: out.txt

c:/python/text1.txt
c:/python/text2.txt
c:/python/text3.txt

```
with open(path, "rb") as sample:
payload = {

    'options': (None,json.dumps (options),'application/json'),'filename':(os.path.basename(path), sample,'application/octet-stream')
}


response = requests.request ("POST", url, headers=headers, files=payload, verify=False)
```

If will run like this >uploading  c:/python/text1.txt...then after the operation it returns back uploading next file

Comment: I have edited the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
import os

directory = r'C:\Users\sample_dir'
for filename in os.listdir(directory):
    -- some operation --
```

Comment: I have added the code .  I need var path will have a path of each file . Once it completes its request of uploading one file, it will open the next file.

Comment: I have added the code .  I need var path will have a path of each file . Once it completes its request of uploading one file, it will again go into loop and put path of the second file in" var path "open the next file.

Answer (score 0):

You can read paths line by line with the for loop you're using.

You're reading in `read-binary` (`rb`) mode, so you'll have to decode it later. Or simply use `r`.

For a proper example look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3277503/how-to-read-a-file-line-by-line-into-a-list).

After you've created a list of paths, Iterate through each path.

```py
for file in paths_list:
   upload_function(file)
```